# Add delay between script execution, especially in FOR loop

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a block of script that will produce a set of DOM. It has a loop that contains an asynchronous function (function A) and then function B after it. Function B's effect will be shown if the asynchronous function (A) is completely executed. I tried to use `setTimeout` function, but it doesn't work well, some of object outside `setTimeout` could not be accessed inside it.
Here's the script:

```
    var parents     = data.hasil.parent.split(">>");
    var jmlparent   = parents.length;
    for (var i = jmlparent-2; i >= 1; i--){
        add_parent();  // it's the asynchronous function (function A)
        setTimeout(function (){
            $("#parent_"+(jmlparent-i)).val(parents[(i-1)]);  //(function B) 
            //returns error: parents is not defined
        },200);
        //i think 200ms is enough for browser to complete the execution of function A
    }
```

Does anyone have the solution?

Comment: You for loop is finished before some `setTimout` function are executed. Try to show `i` inside this function and you will understant

Comment: Can't you make Function A call function B upon returning..which you could also pass as a parameter. Or you don't have any control over Function A

Comment: @MuhammadUmer :function A is used by another functions. if I modify this it will affect all the programs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did not want to discuss the use of `setTimeout` but just improve you code. Try this :

```
...

for (var i = jmlparent-2; i >= 1; i--){
    add_parent();  
    setTimeout(function (a){
        $("#parent_"+(jmlparent-a)).val(parents[(a-1)]);  //(function B) 
    },200, i); // we pass here the i var to setTiemout
}
```

About `add_parent()` why you call it inside the loop ? may be before the loop once is better ?! I dont know ...

Comment: ok i'll try it. `add_parent` must be called because this is the 'core' of it, the lines inside the timeout will affect the result of the 'next'-call of `add_parent`

Comment: how can I pass more variable/object to setTimout? can you show me the reference page?

Comment: setTimeout(func, delay, [param1, param2, ...]);

Answer (score 2):

Function A should return a promise which when resolved you would call function B. You do not know how long function will take to resolve, therefore `setTimeout()` is not a good approach.

You also do need a closure:

```
var parents     = data.hasil.parent.split(">>");
var jmlparent   = parents.length;
for (var i = jmlparent-2; i >= 1; i--){
    (function( i ) {
        add_parent().done(function() {
            $("#parent_"+(jmlparent-i)).val(parents[(i-1)]);  
        });
    })( i );
}
```

Comment: `add_parent` function is `asynchronous`. could it be detected if it was done executing?

Comment: I should be asking you that. Can you show us the code for function A.

Comment: function A contains an ajax call

Comment: So why don't you return a promise from function A and the code above would work just fine: `function add_parent() { ......return $.ajax(); }`